# Ember CLI proxy to a POW server

Tags: ember.js, proxy, ember-cli, node-http-proxy, rack-pow

How can I get EmberCLI to proxy to a POW server? I'm using ember-cli master with the new explicit proxies (https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/1530). This for example doesn't work:

```
var Proxy = require('http-proxy');

// For options, see:
// https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy
var proxy = Proxy.createProxyServer({});

module.exports = function(app) {

  app.use('/', function(req, res, next){
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://api.mywebsite.dev' });
  })

};
```

However, if I change my target to localhost, everything works fine:

```
var Proxy = require('http-proxy');

// For options, see:
// https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy
var proxy = Proxy.createProxyServer({});

module.exports = function(app) {

  app.use('/', function(req, res, next){
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:9292' });
  })

};
```

Comment: My guess is your server isn't setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) and you should be able to tell so by looking at the requests from your brower's developer tools.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue as I set my API to allow requests from any origin on any resource, but I will check it out anyway. thx

Comment: I once experienced CORS issues with my nginx setup, but I think my browser debug tool reported HTTP 404 errors!  I think when I looked at my nginx log, I saw the true cross origin error, so be sure to look at your actual web server logs, even if you're getting a seemingly innocent 404.

Comment: This is most likely due to this: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/696, and fixed with this: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/pull/723.

Comment: Johnny Oshika - Thanks, it worked!